# iptable rule log all ips on port 443

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm on a linux proxy server.  All of our internet traffic is routed through this server. I need to add an iptable rule that will log all ip addresses requested on port 443.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind this won't log any data, but just the details of the request.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j LOG
```

If you wanted to capture more data `tcpdump` is a handy tool